# getting specific errors type message from HTTPError while working django +firebase

Tags: django, firebase-authentication

i was trying to make signup page using django and while using the ff code

```
user = auth_.create_user_with_email_and_password(email, password)
```

while reaching this point it throws  different errors depending on user input
like if user input short password less than 6 characters and also if email is already registered .... with same code error 400 and i need that message to to identify the specific error and display the error back here is the message :

> [Errno 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=AIzaSyBmnhaFGTVelDMkPQ3pjvdPMQc28c-JrTs] {
> "error": {
> "code": 400,
> "message": "WEAK_PASSWORD : Password should be at least 6 characters",
> "errors": [
> {
> "message": "WEAK_PASSWORD : Password should be at least 6 characters",
> "domain": "global",
> "reason": "invalid"
> }
> ]
> }
> }

Comment: What exactly is your issue/question? Looks like you need to capture the error response from the API call and display it? Please provide some more information and code, the context of the request is important, is it a REST API or a form submission?

Comment: my question was wanna get something that is more readable like  'WEAK_PASSWORD'  but i get error like the above one

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.